# How to get Project Site creation date?

Tags: liferay

I created a **Project Site** in **Liferay 6.1.1 CE GA2** and i want to know the creation date of that site using Liferay API.

So, any body can help me out?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Liferay stores informations about a site in many tables but the site identifier is the group stored in _group table.

Columns from this table's rows are mapped into the Group interface from Liferay API. http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/model/Group.html

Unfortunately no creation date is stored in this table, consequently the Group interface it's unuseful.

Anyway I founded that when you create a new site, two layout sets are created into the layoutset table (private and public) and creation dates for those are stored. So as a sort of hack you could use information from those layout sets to know when your site was created.

Don't know if it's your case but for example the LayoutSetLocalServiceUtil class could be used in portlet jsp page this way:

```java
<%
    long groupId = company.getGroupId();
    LayoutSet sitePrivateLayoutSet = LayoutSetLocalServiceUtil.getLayoutSet(groupId, true);
    Date siteCreationDate = sitePrivateLayoutSet.getCreateDate();
%>
```

Note that you will need liferay theme taglib initialized this way:

```java
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/theme" prefix="liferay-theme" %>
<liferay-theme:defineObjects />
```

Hope this helps!